# change the background image as you onmousemove on the different images javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function upDate(previewPic) {

    /* In this function you should
    1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image"
    to the source file of the preview image
    2) Change the text of the div with the id = "image"
    to the alt text of the preview image
    */

    var m = document.getElementById("image");
    m.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg')";
    var p = document.getElementById('image');
    p.innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}

function unDo() {

    /* In this function you should
    1) Update the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image"
    back to the orginal-image. You can use the css code to see what that original URL was
    2) Change the text of the div with the id = "image"
    back to the original text. You can use the html code to see what that original text was
    */

    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
    document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = "Hover over an image to display here";
}
```

Comment: why not change the image in the css?

Comment: do you have the html to go along with this

Comment: I got one div in html with id= image..

Comment: more then one pictures in HTML.. what i want them is to show that image into div box as i moveover on the pictures.

Comment: Isn't this homework (hence the comments)?

Comment: I tried my best since 2 days but could not get it right, That's why asked for help..

Comment: If there aren't so many images, it is a better practice to use CSS classes and simply toggle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in JS,

`document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroungImage = url(" ") ;`

Images in Html are already saved in src so, previewPic.src will be images link.

Don't forget to concatenation ..
like this `"url" + "(" + parameters.src + ")" ;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is homework thus I only give you a partial answer here:

```
function upDate(previewPic) {
    /* In this function you should
    1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image"
    to the source file of the preview image
    2) Change the text of the div with the id = "image"
    to the alt text of the preview image
    */

    var m = document.getElementById("image");
    // now how would I fix this string concatenation up? hmmm
    m.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + previewPic.whattoplacehere +')";
    // comment out as we have this  var p = document.getElementById('image');
    // change to m from p as we had it already.
    m.innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}
```

What event do we need?  We need two it seems, what is the second one?

```
var myimage = document.getElementById("myimage");
myimage.addEventListener("mousesomething", function(event) {
  var target = event.target,
    related = event.relatedTarget;
  upDate(what should be here?);
}, false);
```

Research:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent